# Add a label after a String

Tags: swift, string, uilabel

I need to create a line of text with two colors

There will Be a text, which is string in black and there will be one $ Symbol and it should be red.

```
lazy var dollarSmb: UILabel = {
      let smb = UILabel()
      smb.text = "$"
      smb.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: .regular)
      smb.textColor = UIColor.red
      smb.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
      smb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      return smb
   }()
```

And I want to add it after the label string, something like that:

```
Var label = "This is a test" + " \(dollarSmb)"
```

It's not working

Could anyone help me the best way to do that?
Many thanks

Comment: Use an `NSAttributedString` to have different colors and fonts in one string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `NSAttributedString` to construct a single string with a different color.

```swift
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is a test ")
let dollarSymbl = NSAttributedString(string: "$", attributes: [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
attributedString.append(dollarSymbl)

// Then assign it to a UILabel
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `NSAttributedString` and instead of setting `smb.text`, set `smb.attributedText`.

Something like

```
smb.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "$", attributes [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
```